# Windows XP - server process (svchost.exe -k netsvcs) starts after about 10 minutes

Tags: windows, process, windows-xp

I have a problem with server process in Windows XP (C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs). When I reboot system this process is in running stage and it end after 10 minutes:( It is very strange, because after this event windows works perfect.

No problem in windows log.

I thought it is a Virus but I checked system and do COMBOFIX. No change.

Any idea? 
Regards

Comment: Off-topic: Not related to programming.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
As I wrote the process name is "Server" and it runs **svchost.exe -k netsvcs** 
This process is responsible for networking, etc. For 10 minutest at the begining of starting windows I can't for example connect remotely, iis can't work too.

Comment: That's a hardware/software issue - SO is for programming issues.

Answer (score 2):

Svchost is a process that hosts services. It is essential for many windows programs to function, and simply killing it will not help and may stop something important from functioning. If you get sysinternals process explorer you can see what processes are linked to the particular svchost you are having trouble with so you can then uninstall or stop it.